# In bash, why does it output a right bracket as a value in when replacing?

Tags: bash, shell

So I was looking into `tr` and I was playing around with the following command:
`echo "test 123 new LINE" | tr -c 'A-Za-z' '[\n*]'` vs `echo "test 123 new LINE" | tr -c 'A-Za-z' '[\n]'`. These are the different outputs:

```
> echo "test 123 new LINE" | tr -c 'A-Za-z' '[\n*]'
test




new
LINE
> echo "test 123 new LINE" | tr -c 'A-Za-z' '[\n]'
test]]]]]new]LINE]
```

Without the addition of the wildcard, it appears to be replacing each new line with a right bracket character. Taking a look at the man page (https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html), it says that for the argument [CHAR*], it "in SET2, copies of CHAR until length of SET1". So clearly it still replaces characters in SET1 based on SET2 but where is it getting the right bracket from?

Nothing to do with my job so no need to tell me about sed or awk, just came across this and was curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second command, the replacement set is not in one of the special formats

```
[CHAR*]
[CHAR*REPEAT]
[:<keyword>:]
[=CHAR=]
```

So it doesn't get any special treatment and the square brackets are treated literally. So the first two non-alphabetic characters are replaced with `[` and `\n`, respectively, and all other characters are replaced with `]` (because the replacement set is extended by repeating the last character).

Comment: You can see this quite clearly when SET1 is not complemented. Try `echo "abcdefghijkl" | tr 'c-i' '[\n]'`, and you'll get "ab[<newline>]]]]]jkl". To see something other than the last character in SET2 with a complemented set, try the first few control characters: `printf '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04' | tr -c 'A-Za-z' '[\n]'`

Comment: oh my gosh, that makes sense. I kept seeing "CHAR*" as a separate filter not "[CHAR*]" as the entire filter. Was taking the square brackets literally. Thank you that makes sense!

Comment: @Barmar: A bit off-topic, but what is the meaning of `[=CHAR=]`? The man-page just says _all characters which are equivalent to CHAR_, but does not define what _equivalent_ means in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure, either. Maybe it can be used for something like "all whitespace characters". You could try asking in [unix.se]. Or look at the GNU source code.